# Freeware ISO editor

Tags: windows, gratis, iso

I'm looking for a freeware ISO disc image editor:

- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- no adware
- runs on Windows (Vista)
- add/remove files from ISO images
- preserve boot information for both Linux and Windows ISOs

I know about [PowerISO](http://poweriso.com/), but the trial version is limited to 300 MB ISO size.